# Why is my OpenGL texture black (in Dear ImGUI)?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, imgui

In OpenGL 4.6, I (attempt to) create and initialize a solid color texture as follows:

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &_textureHandle);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0); // This doesn't change the outcome
std::vector<unsigned char> data(3 * WIDTH * HEIGHT, static_cast<unsigned char>(200));
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
```

I then use the texture in Dear ImGUI like this:

```
ImGui::Image((void*)(intptr_t) _textureHandle, ImVec2(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

However, this simply shows a black texture.

I also tried a different way of initialization (to no avail):

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[3 * WIDTH * HEIGHT];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (int)(WIDTH * HEIGHT); i++) {
    data[i * 3] = (unsigned char)255;
    data[i * 3 + 1] = (unsigned char)50;
    data[i * 3 + 2] = (unsigned char)170;
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the texture by OpenGL 4.5 DSA, but didn't use DSA to set the texture parameters and image.
You have to use `glTextureParameter`, `glTextureStorage2D` and `glTextureSubImage2D` instead of `glTexParameter` and `glTexImage2D`.

```cpp
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &_textureHandle);
glTextureParameteri(_textureHandle, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(_textureHandle, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(_textureHandle, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(_textureHandle, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
std::vector<unsigned char> data(3 * WIDTH * HEIGHT, static_cast<unsigned char>(200));
glTextureStorage2D(_textureHandle, 1, GL_RGB8, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glTextureSubImage2D(_textureHandle, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there were functions that combined `Gen` and `Bind` calls, but I didn't know that was called DSA and I didn't know those two types of function couldn't be used interchangeably. One thing though: the internal format argument for `glTextureStorage2D()` needs to be `GL_RGB8` instead of `GL_RGB`.

Answer (score 1):

If don't generate [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (with [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)) you must set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to a non mipmap filter. The texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete" if you do not change the minifying function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

Eiter generate mipmaps:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Or use `GL_LINEAR` for the minifying function:

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP);
```